# Uploading video to vimeo using its API while bypassing php server limits

Tags: vimeo

I have a code that uses [vimeo upload API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload) to submit video files to vimeo using a form in a WorpPress site.

The process works fine as long as the video file size is below the file upload limit of the web server. Is there a way in the vimeo upload API to bypass any of the file upload limitations of my web server and use a direct approach to upload the video file to vimeo?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I couldn't post it here so I put it on GH:

https://gist.github.com/f153fdf605d4fdcc6233.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimeo's simple POST uploader goes right from the client to vimeo's servers.

Check out the documentation here : https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload#http-post-uploading

Comment: Is this opposed to 'streaming'? Isn't the 'streaming' method should also be directly from the client to vimeo?

Comment: Streaming method can be set up that way, but it's a little more difficult. Any method that happens in the browser, directly to Vimeo's servers should solve the problem.

Comment: Will do as you suggested and report with the results afterwards. Thank you Dashron.

Comment: I tested your suggestion and it did exactly as you said. Thank you.